# Reseting variables for new user in Telegram bot (python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot which responds with different messages depending on the value `funcnex.state` has.

Function is operating with this class:

```
class FuncCreator:
    def __init__(self, start_state):
        self.state = start_state

    def __call__(self):
        print(self.state)
        self.state += 1

funcnex = FuncCreator(0)
```

The answer message is defined like this:

```
 elif ' Next' in text:
            if funcnex.state == 0:
                b2 = u'\U0001F532'+' Next'
                line1 = linecache.getline('stattxt/sc1-1.txt', 6)
                line2 = linecache.getline('stattxt/sc1-1.txt', 7)
                json_keyboard = json.dumps({keym: [[b2]], 'resize_keyboard': True, 'one_time_keyboard': False})
                reply(u'\U000025FC'+line1+'\n'+line2)              
                funcnex()
            elif funcnex.state == 1:
                b2 = u'\U000027A1'+' Next'
                line1 = linecache.getline('stattxt/sc1-1.txt', 12)
                line2 = linecache.getline('stattxt/sc1-1.txt', 13)
                json_keyboard = json.dumps({keym: [[b2]], 'resize_keyboard': True, 'one_time_keyboard': False})
                reply(u'\U0001F532'+line1+'\n'+line2)                
                funcnex()
```

The problem is that if several users interact with the bot, the  `funcnex.state` for the new user could already be `1` or higher, if some user previously interacted with the bot.

The question is - how can I reset it for every *new* user?

Meaning that, for example,

If one user sends the word `Next` to the bot for the first time, they would receive answer 1. When he sends the word `Next` for second time, he would receive answer 2, and so on.

To count amount of times user send word `Next`, I am using the function that is in the example. If there would be only one user everything works fine, but for second user when `counter` should have value `0` for the start, now he gets the value of counter that previous user gained.

Comment: Why not create an instance per user?

Comment: Thank you for response! What instance do you mean? How it could look like? Sorry for the noob questions, this is my student project.

Comment: Of `FuncCreator`, the thing that's doing the counting. Create a new one for each new user.

Comment: Could you share an idea how it may look like?

Comment: It looks like exactly how you currently create one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I have unique varibale in `class WebhookHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler)` which is `chat_id = chat['id']`. How would I implement this in `FuncCreator` for every chat, so it would count separately for each user?

Comment: Using variables in this case is a bad practice. What is the reason in this usage?

Comment: @anatol - I feel that it's not good, but I need somehow to track user answers. Meaning that, for example, If one user sends to bot word "Next"  for the first time - he receives answer 1, when he sends the word "Next" for second time, he receives answer 2 and so on. To count amount of times user send word "Next" I use function that is in example. If there would be only one user everything works fine, but for second user counter should has 0 value for the start, but now he gets the value of counter that previous user gained. Please, share idea how to manage it proper way.

Comment: Should you add this description to your question?

Comment: @anatol updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for this situation - take a look at [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup). It's more elegantly for you instead variables etc. Just set `callback_data` for [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), catch it after user click, do something and change `callback_data` at the end.
For example bot sends message to user with inline button there text "Next" and callback data is 0. After user click you need catch [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) in your [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) results. If it equal 0 - do something for this. Then you need change message with inline button - use [Updating messages](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages). Edit message and set for inline button new value of `callback_data`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this. I'll try it!